# Trying to parent a part of an object's mesh to an armature bone after I parented the mesh to armature

Tags: rigging

When I went to move the neck of a unicorn model I made in blender and parented to an armature, after adding and removing bones and adding bones  following some tutorials on bendy bones to make the unicorn's neck flexible. This happened: [image]

Do I need to start the armature over completely?

Or is there a way to attach the neck's vertices to the neck part of the armature " the bone that is bendy for the neck. "  I can't find any option in blender that allows you to add a vertex group created after the armature is parented to a mesh, to the bone in question. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Please use print screen to take screenshots, not a camera.

Comment: I guess you need to make some corrections in Weight Paint mode, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: That is kind of hard to do from my phone my PC has no internet connection so please forgive my lack of screenshot and use of phone camera. As for sending the file, I can't because I do not want the model to be stolen.

Comment: Overall I feel like this whole thing has been wholely unhelpful. I'll just redo the armature since this is the kind of response I get. Even if I wasted a few hours on the current one.